# How to drag & drop image from desktop to dropbox

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new in ruby on rails, and i'm trying some code for drag and drop image. But, i only drag image from my dragbox to my dropbox in html, but i can't drag image from desktop into my dropbox. There is my code:

My javascript

```
<script>
    function doFirst() {
        mypic = document.getElementById('pic');
        mypic.addEventListener("dragstart", startDrag, false);

        leftbox = document.getElementById('leftbox');
        leftbox.addEventListener("dragenter", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault()
        }, false);
        leftbox.addEventListener("dragover", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault()
        }, false);
        leftbox.addEventListener("drop", dropped, false);
    }

    function startDrag(e) {
        var code = '<img src="/assets/Koala.jpg">';
        e.dataTransfer.setData('Text', code);
    }

    function dropped(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        leftbox.innerHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData('Text');
    }
    window.addEventListener("load", doFirst, false); 
</script>
<section id="leftbox"></section>
<section id="rightbox">
    <img id="pic" src="/assets/Koala.jpg" />
</section>
```

My css

```
#leftbox{
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    margin: 5px;
    border: 3px solid blue;
}
#rightbox{
  float: left;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 3px solid green;
};
```

How do i drag and drop image from desktop? please!help me

Answer (score 0):

In a case of dealing with files you should modify your `dropped` handler to:

```
  function dropped(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var files = e.dataTransfer.files;
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      var file = files[i];
      // now you are free to do whatever you want with file, e.g.: 
      new FileReader().readAsDataURL(file);
    }
  }
```

You might also want to check [W3C specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-upload/).
Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry, it's don't work. May be i should modify the same thing in function startDrag

Comment: `startDrag` would not be even called whether you drag files from your desctop.